# ajax on webform

Tags: 7, ajax, webforms

I have added a button to webform:

```
   $form['submitted']['some_placeholder']['own_btn'] = array(
       '#type' => 'button',
       '#value' => t('Add'),
       '#name' => 'ob_add_food',
       '#weight' => 19,
       '#prefix' => '<td>',
       '#suffix' => '</td></tr></table>',

       '#limit_validation_errors' => array(),
       '#ajax' => array(
          'callback' => 'callback_js',
          'wrapper' => 'wrapper-div',
          'method' => 'replace',
          'effect' => 'fade',
          'speed' => 'slow',
    ),
);
```

and callback_js:

```
  function callback_js($form, $form_state) {
     return  $form['submitted']['some_placeholder'];
  }
```

When I go to it form admin user(Administration -> Content....) and view it, everything works fine, but when I go to it from simple user(I show form at first screen) callback does not work?
Any ideas?

Comment: Clear caches, maybe?

Comment: @user3161584 no, doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `'#type' => 'button',` to `'#type' => 'submit',`.

Comment: do not help. Maybe problem in permissions